# Bash eating stderr output

Tags: macos, bash, shell, stdout, stderr

I'm calling a command line tool we wrote from bash on OS X and I have the problem that I don't get the stderr output but only printf's written to stdout.

That's my call:

```
echo "someInputString" |theTool -v someArg
```

I also tried:

```
echo "someInputString" |theTool -v someArg 2>&1
```

without success...
I bet it's trivial but I don't know what needs to be done.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot see any difference between the two lines.

Comment: @fedorqui Sorry, missed it. Edited the question.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the second command (or the first command). I'm guessing that it's the tool's problem. Or perhaps /dev/stderr is inherently /dev/null or something invalid.

Try to run '[[ -t 2 ]] && echo valid' without single quotes to check current shell's stderr.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the stderr stream output with `2>`.

```
echo "someInputString" |theTool -v someArg 2> error_file
```