# How to pipe this process output to 1) a textfile 2) python script

Tags: python, bash, pipe, output

I would like to pipe the output of the following process either 1) into a text file or 2) into another python script (to process it directly)

```
java -jar tools/PlayGame.jar tools/maps/8planets/map1.txt "python BullyBot.py" "python MinMaxBot.py" parallel | python tools/visualizer/visualize_locally.py
```

I am sorry for the long command but i did not wish to leave out information. This command works, with the necessary files at least.

This is the content of the visualize_locally.py file:

```
import re
import sys  
import os
import webbrowser

def generate(data, generated_path):
  path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
  template_path = os.path.join(path, 'index.php')
  template = open(template_path, 'r')
  content = template.read()
  template.close()

  php_re = re.compile(r"<\?php.*?\?>", re.S)
  javascript = "var data = '%s';" % data
  content = php_re.sub(javascript, content)

  output = open(generated_path, 'w')
  output.write(content)
  output.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  data = raw_input()

  path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
  generated_path = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(path, 'generated.htm'))

  generate(data, generated_path)
  webbrowser.open('file://'+generated_path)
```

In the python files given as parameters to the java command, the following log function is used:

```
def log(self, *args):
    lst=[]
    for arg in args:
        lst.append(str(arg))
    lst.append('\n')#needed, otherwise line won't show in console
    sys.stderr.write(' '.join(lst))
    sys.stderr.flush()
```

The output visible in my terminal window looks like this:

```
futuremaggel:PlanetWars supermaggel$ ./testbot.sh
Engine entering main game loop. Mode 'parallel'
Player 2: MIN score: 5.88349514563 
Player 2: MIN score: 6.26699029126 
Player 2: MIN score: 5.83495145631 
Player 2: MIN score: 5.48058252427 
Player 2: MIN score: 5.95145631068 
Player 2: MIN score: 6.44174757282 
Player 2: MIN score: 3.0 
Player 2: best move for MAX is thus: 6.44174757282 
Turn 1
```

The `testbot.sh` shell script only contains the command mentioned at the beginning of my question. I have tried to do this:

```
java -jar tools/PlayGame.jar tools/maps/8planets/map1.txt "python BullyBot.py" "python MinMaxBot.py" parallel | python tools/visualizer/visualize_locally.py > gamelog.txt
```

Which does not work, `gamelog.txt` is created afterwards but is an empty file.
(I think that's because the output that i see in my terminal window is created at run-time - so maybe the output is piped too fast and it misses the actual output?)

I've also tried the suggestions here: [Bash eating stderr output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034286/bash-eating-stderr-output) and here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/

Comment: Can you try `your command 2&>1 | tee "gamelog.txt"`

Comment: @BroSlow i tried but that yields 2 empty files, a file '1' and the empty gamelog.txt file!

Comment: Are you sure you used `2&>1` instead of `2>1`?

Comment: Yes, doublechecked just now. I have added some more information to my original question to make clear what is used and how!

Comment: @BroSlow It's `2>&1`, not `2&>1`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the correction, realized it was wrong in my answer, forgot to change it in comment. Always get it confused in bash since `>&` and `&>` are equivalent without file descriptors, but not with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting an answer so as to avoid filling up the comments.

If you're getting output from

```
$ java -jar tools/PlayGame.jar tools/maps/8planets/map1.txt "python BullyBot.py" "python MinMaxBot.py" parallel | python tools/visualizer/visualize_locally.py
```

in a terminal. That can mean one of four things.

- You're getting stderr from java
- You're getting stderr from python
- You're getting stdout from python
- You're getting a combination of stdout and stderr from python

You can not be getting stdout from java, since that got piped to python and wouldn't be visible in your terminal unless python displayed it.

Now to check if you're getting stderr from java, do

```
$ java -jar tools/PlayGame.jar tools/maps/8planets/map1.txt "python BullyBot.py" "python MinMaxBot.py" parallel 1>/dev/null
```

If you see **anything** than you were getting stderr previously.

That means you have two ways to handle it. If you think python will process it correctly, you can pipe it to python like so

```
$ java -jar tools/PlayGame.jar tools/maps/8planets/map1.txt "python BullyBot.py" "python MinMaxBot.py" parallel 2>&1 | python tools/visualizer/visualize_locally.py &> output.txt
```

In which case output.txt will get all output returned by python. If you don't think python will handle stderr properly, you can redirect that to a file and then append python output to it.

```
$ java -jar tools/PlayGame.jar tools/maps/8planets/map1.txt "python BullyBot.py" "python MinMaxBot.py" parallel 2>output.txt | python tools/visualizer/visualize_locally.py >> output.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: When i add 1>/dev/null and run the command, i see exactly the output that i saw before, so yes to that question. However, both &> output.txt and >> output.txt 2>&1 yield an empty file :(

Comment: @MichaelTrouw And you have the respective 2>&1 and 2>output.txt respectively as well? (note you're using 2>&1 and not 2&>1 like I put in some comment before)

Comment: oh i did not see the addition to the first commands before piping, the last one works flawlessly (the first one didn't). Thanks! solved.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 types of output files that any command produces: stdout and stderr. Here's a brief summary of command line directioning.

> command > file  **(dump stdout into file)**
>
> command 2&>1   **(catch stderr, make it part of stdout)**
>
> command | command2 **(grab the stdout from command and dump it into stdin for command2)**
>
> command >> file.txt  **(append to existing file)**

I don't know whats the contents of visualize_locally.py but for the particular chain you have to work, it also needs to print printing whatever it got through stdin into stdout? Otherwise the python script is eating all the data. Make sure it has a line similar to this:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
  print line
```

****Edit*** I saw you updated your post with the contents of the python file. Looks like yes, the python file is eating the output and writing it somewhere else and it makes perfect sense why your gamelog.txt is empty.

If you ran the exact command but without "> gamelog.txt" do you see something getting printed to the screen?

Comment: I just added the contents of the visualize_locally.py file in the original post. oops, i think i need to mention that i use a given log function, code also added above.

Comment: I just added an update, looks like your python command is not printing anything out therefore your files that you are writing are going to be empty.

Comment: as answer to your last question, yes i do get output in my terminal window.

Comment: aha, i see what you mean.. it is not the last python script producing the output, therefore any piping will result in nothing... But how can i capture the output of the python files that are invoked from java? the java jar itself generates output as well that i do NOT wish to capture :(

Comment: @MichaelTrouw That makes no difference, unless what you're seeing is stderr from java. In which case it depends on how you want to deal with it. To check if it is stderr run, `java -jar tools/PlayGame.jar tools/maps/8planets/map1.txt "python BullyBot.py" "python MinMaxBot.py" parallel 2>/dev/null`. If you see nothing, then what you were seeing before is stderr, and then you have to decide how to handle it (pipe it to python, pipe it directly to a file, etc...)

Comment: sorry, but `command > file` will send stdout to `file` but leave stderr to stream to the terminal. That's the whole purpose of keeping stdout separate from stderr. Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter thanks for the feedback. I fixed my answer, can I have my points back? :)

Comment: @JuanCarlosMoreno : yep! Also, I think your second example is limited to new versions of bash. The traditional way to merge stdout and stderr is `command 1>stdout.txt 2>&1` (Assumming you want to redirect the stdout to a file). OR just `command 2>&1` . Good luck to all.